# VBA Difference between Set and Assignment

Tags: vba, parsing

I'm reading the source code of VBA-JSON, which is located at:

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas

In the function that dumps JSON objects (starting with "{" char) into memory:

```
Private Function json_ParseObject(json_String As String, ByRef json_Index As Long) As Dictionary
Dim json_Key As String
Dim json_NextChar As String

Set json_ParseObject = New Dictionary
json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) <> "{" Then
    Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(json_String, json_Index, "Expecting '{'")
Else
    json_Index = json_Index + 1

    Do
        json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
        If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = "}" Then
            json_Index = json_Index + 1
            Exit Function
        ElseIf VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = "," Then
            json_Index = json_Index + 1
            json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
        End If

        json_Key = json_ParseKey(json_String, json_Index)
        json_NextChar = json_Peek(json_String, json_Index)
        If json_NextChar = "[" Or json_NextChar = "{" Then
            Set json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)
        Else
            json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)
        End If
    Loop
End If
End Function
```

What is the difference between:

```
Set json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)
```

And the following one:

```
json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)
```

I searched in SO and found this post, which does not dispel the confusion:

[What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba)

From reading the code, I understand that if the parser reads a "{" or "[", then it needs to use a Dictionary to hold whatever between "{" and "}", and a Collection to hold whatever between "[" and "]", and if the parser reads something other than those two, then it is just a value, could be Boolean or String or Integer, etc.

What I don't get is the difference between Set and Assignment. "Set" will copy the address of the return variable of json_ParseValue, and assignment simply makes another copy of the return variable. Is it because that in the first case, there is further requirement to modify the returned object so it has to be passed by address (like in C++ we use &)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the linked Q&A says, `Set` is used in VBA to assign an object reference. The `Let` keyword can be used to assign values, but the `Let` keyword is pretty much obsolete/redundant.

This is why you have these keywords in property mutator definitions though:

```
Private mSomething As Variant

Public Property Let Something(ByVal value As Variant)
    mSomething = value ' value is a primitive
End Property

Public Property Set Something(ByVal value As Variant)
    Set mSomething = value ' value is an object reference
End Property
```

So far, so good. The difference between this:

> ```
> Set json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)
> ```

And this:

> ```
> json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)
> ```

Is that because `json_ParseValue` returns a `Variant` that can hold anything including an object reference or a simple value, then it needs to use the `Set` keyword when assigning a reference, and leave it out (or use the `Let` keyword) when assigning a value.

---

It's impossible to tell without looking at the implementation details and seeing exactly what is being returned, but it's also possible that a `Let` assignment could be assigning to a default member - and that default member call is implicit, and bloody confusing indeed.

It's exactly the same as when you're assigning a cell value in Excel VBA:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
```

vs

```
Dim r As Double
r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'implicit call to ActiveSheet.Range("A1").[_Default]
```

The two instructions **look** different only because one has a `Set` keyword and the other doesn't, however the real difference is an **implicit member call to a hidden property** named `[_Default]`, that has a `VB_UserMemId = 0` attribute which makes that member the class' *default member*.

The confusion stems from *implicit default member calls*, which make the code *say* something, and actually *do* something else.

[Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (an OSS VBIDE add-in project I manage) has a code inspection that locates implicit default member assignments in early-bound code:

> **Implicit default member assignment**
>
> Such assignments look like they are assigning an object variable to a value type on the surface, but they are actually assigning that object's default member, implicitly. Consider referring to the default member explicitly, for improved readability.

Comment: @Nicholas - There we go, I told you someone would quickly post a more in-depth answer than mine....  this one only took "–14 seconds".  Now *that's* fast.

Comment: @ashleedawg actually, I took a look at the code, and it has nothing to do with implicit default member assignment - simply, the function is returning a `Variant` that may hold a value or an object reference. `Set` is required to assign the reference, ...and that's all there is to it. Still, implicit default member assignment is good to know I guess =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks! Oh now I got it, because if the parser needs to parse a JSON object/array, it needs to hold it with a Dictionary/Collection, which has to be <code>Set</code>. For other cases (JSON integer/string/boolean/etc.) the variables returned are of primitive and cannot be <code>Set</code>

Comment: @ashleedawg :D I still very much want to read your implementation of a JSON parser. I pretty much taught myself C++ and some data structure a while ago, but I uses VBA everyday so it makes sense to go a bit deeper in CS with VBA (However the lack of access to C/C++ pointers do annoy me).

Answer (score 2):

The three types you are referring to are **dictionary**, **collection**, and **array**.  Basically, any combination of those can make up a JSON structure.

Someone with more time will probably give a better answer, but the gist of it is (in my over-simplified interpretation),

- Assigning a value to a variable makes a **copy** of that value.
- `Set` is used for objects because instead of copying the object, it creates a **reference** to the object.

> Generally, when you use Set to assign an object reference to a variable, no copy of the object is created for that variable. Instead, a reference to the object is created. **More than one object variable can refer to the same object.** Because such variables are references to the object rather than copies of the object, **any change in the object is reflected in all variables that refer to it**. However, when you use the New keyword in the Set statement, you are actually creating an *instance* of the object. <sub>([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/set-statement))</sub>

---

### More Information:

- w3resource : ✴ [**Structures of JSON**](https://www.w3resource.com/JSON/structures.php)  ✴
- MSDN : [**Set Statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/set-statement)
- MSDN : [**Declaring Variables**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-variables)
- MSDN : [**Creating Object Variables**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/creating-object-variables)
- Wikipedia : [**Object-oriented programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)
- Stack Overflow : [**What is the opposite of OOP**?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6295260/8112776)

Comment: I'll expand later but I need to get back to work, coincidentally on my own form of an Excel-based JSON parser, as I've never been a fan of `VBA-JSON`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I now understand the difference between <code>Set</code> and <code>=</code>. What confuses me is why the author uses <code>Set</code> when he needs to parse JSON object/array? I'm going to remove it to see what happens. BTW may I ask the reason you dislike VBA-JSON?